# Submit form in Python 3

Tags: python, mechanize, urllib

I am trying to submit a form using Python 3. In Python 2 I did the following:

```
br=mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handler_robots(False)  
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]  
br.open(url)  
br.select_form(nr=0)  
br.form['form_name']=entry  
br.submit()
```

It works. In Python 3 I tried to do it using the following code:

```
data={'form_name':entry}  
data=urllib.parse.urlencode(data)  
data=data.encode('utf-8')
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1'}  
req=urllib.request.Request(url,data,headers)  
response=urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

But its showing HTTP Error 405. Can anyone please explain how to work it out in Python 3?

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests)? It is Python 3 compatible and much more pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Error 405 is [Method Not Allowed](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), so you probably aren't allowed to POST to that URL.

An `urllib.request.Request` automatically changes its HTTP method to POST when you pass it data, but it's also possible to submit forms through GET by adding the form parameters to the URL, which is probably what the website is expecting. See if the `<form>` tag has its `method` attribute set to "get" in the HTML (or if it's missing entirely, in which case it defaults to "get").

You can add the form parameters to the URL manually like this:

```
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(data)
req = urllib.request.Request("%s?%s" % (url, data), headers=headers)
```

(That's hacky, but [used as an example in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html#examples), so I guess it's the preferred way.)

Since you're not passing data to the constructor, the method it will use will be GET.

That may work. Since web servers are free to return whatever status code they please, though, the problem may be something else entirely.

Comment: I think, the problem is something else. I checked the method. Its POST. So when I did with requests.post using the module requests it worked.